# Github actions secret of gcp service account not parsed correctly

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, github-actions, google-iam

I have created a GCP service account having the `roles/storageAdmin` role.

I have tested it locally as follows:

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=myfile.json

$ gcloud auth configure-docker

$ docker push gcr.io/my-project-id/echoserver:1.0.1
```

I then create a repo-level secret with the contents of this file named `GCR_SECRET` and run the following [action](https://github.com/RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action)

```
    - name: build and push to staging gcr
      id: stg_img_build
      uses: RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action@v4
      with:
        gcloud_service_key: ${{ secrets.GCR_SECRET }}
        registry: gcr.io
        project_id: $STAGING_GCR_PROJECT
        image_name: ${{ github.event.inputs.image_name }}
        image_tag:  ${{ github.event.inputs.image_tag }}
```

This fails as follows:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://gcr.io/v2/": unknown: Unable to parse json key.
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to consider [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#github-actions) as this will enable you to federate auth using a Google Service Account to GitHub Actions.

See [Enabling keyless auth from GitHub Actions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions).

If you want to use [RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action](https://github.com/RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action), note the requirement to [base64 encode the key](https://github.com/RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action#gcloud_service_key) before persisting it to the repo.